# Removing index.php from joomla url 2.5

Tags: php, .htaccess, joomla, indexing

Hi I want to remove index.php from my joomla website, most places that i read it said that it would work if i change htaccess.txt file to .htaccess and then select yes for SEO Settings
Search Engine Friendly URLs and Use URL rewriting. After doing that, instead of getting a more user friendly url i get this

http://www.smass2.co.uk/websites/123reg/LinuxPackage25/sm/as/s2/smass2.co.uk/public_html/en/

So i reversed the settings agian until i can figure out how to do it. Any help?

Comment: The htaccess file relies on the server to be configured to understand it. What type of hosting are you running the site on?

Comment: Have you made any other changes on the htaccess file, or is there any other special configuration on your website?  It seems like something may be wrong with the configuration of the server. I would suggest to contact your hosting provider and explain them your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Your answer is here:

Here You will find useful information on how to setup Your server for joomla
http://docs.joomla.org/Enabling_Search_Engine_Friendly_(SEF)_URLs

As well as that I would read apache manual especially part on RewriteBase: 
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase

I hope this helps

Comment: I am glad that I could help You :)

Answer (score 0):

/** Remove index.php from joomla 3.3 **/

I am using joomla 3.3.

**Goto Admin:**

1. http://domain.com/administrator/
2. Type username & password
   3.System-->Global Configuration
3. SEO Setting:Search Engine Friendly URLs: Yes & Use URL rewriting:Yes

**Change htaccess.txt file**

I found that in my joomla directory there is one file "htaccess.txt".

Just remove # from RewriteBase / (ie. #RewriteBase / => to RewriteBase /)

And now upload into root directory where your joomla install into domain.

And rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess file